# Como usar o try catch para tratar erro da váriavel id no FindOrFail

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function finalizarCompra () {
  try {
    $compra = Compra::findOrFail($compra->id);
  }
  catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
    return "erro";
  }    
}
```

Comment: O que acontece nesse caso? é lançada uma exception?

Comment: consegue já resolver meu problema ! rray, sou iniciante na programação consegui resolver já !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caleb,

Caso a sua função retorne false vc precisa forçar um erro com o throw, segue:

```
public function finalizarCompra () {
    try {
        $compra = Compra::findOrFail($compra->id);

        if (!$compra) {
            throw new Exception('Não encontrado');
        }

    }
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
        return "erro";
    }
}
```